# python 3 regular expression match string meta-character

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, string-matching

I want to write a line of regular expression that can match strings like "(2000)" with years in parentheses. then I can check if any string contains the substring "2000".

for example, I want the regex to match (2000) not 2000, or (20000),or (200).
That is to say: they have to have exactly four digits, the first digit between 1 and 2; they have to include the parentheses.

also 2000 is just an example I use but really I want to the regex to include all the possible years.

Comment: what do you want? can you give us sample of string matching and not matching ?

Comment: You can simply use `\(\d+\)`

Comment: thank you, solved by \([1-2](\d{3})\)

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the open and close paranthesis,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = """foo(2000)bar(1000)foobar2000"""
>>> regex = r'\(2000\)'
>>> result = re.findall(regex, str)
>>> print(result)
['(2000)']
```

OR

```
>>> import re
>>> str = """foo(2000)bar(1000)foobar(2014)barfoo(2020)"""
>>> regex = r'\([0-9]{4}\)'
>>> result = re.findall(regex, str)
>>> print(result)
['(2000)', '(1000)', '(2014)', '(2020)']
```

It matches all the four digit numbers(year's) present within the paranthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters need to be escaped with a backslash. A parenthesis `(` becomes `\(`. Therefore `(2000)` becomes `\(2000\)`.

Then you can do something like:

```
if re.search(r"\(2000\)", subject):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> x = re.match(r'\((\d*?)\)', "(2000)")
>>> x.group(1)
'2000'
```